# Google Licensing Library (LVL) is empty googleplaylicensing.jar

Tags: android, eclipse, android-library, android-lvl

I've been working on the latest version of one of my apps all week and today, I randomly started getting a bunch of errors about the license checking library. I'm using Eclipse and I downloaded the latest Android SDK and the Google Play Licensing Library so that I would be using the latest versions of the APIs.

I created an LVL project in my workspace, and I changed my app's project properties to reference the LVL project as an Android Library.

[image]

However, when I try to reference the classes in the LVL project, they are not found. I checked my project's Build Path to make sure it was including the GooglePlayLicensing project and it does:

[image]

So, I can see it is referencing the googleplaylicensing.jar from the LVL project but when I build that project the googleplaylicensing.jar file it creates is empty. It only has a jar Manifest, but no class files:

```
palanthas:~/AndroidWorkspace/GooglePlayLicensing/bin$ jar tvf googleplaylicensing.jar 
     2 Sat Mar 02 17:45:50 PST 2013 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
palanthas:~/AndroidWorkspace/GooglePlayLicensing/bin$
```

I double checked that the GooglePlayLicensing project had the java sources in the Build Path, thinking that maybe somehow they were excluded and that's why nothing was being built. However, the src/ and the gen/ directories are both included in the Java Build Path.

[image]

Why isn't the LVL jar being built correctly? How can I fix it so that I can reference those files in my android app project?

NOTE: I know that I can copy the sources into my android project, but that's not an acceptable solution for this problem. I need it to be easily reusable because we have many apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. Something must have gone horribly wrong when I imported the LVL project into my Android workspace, because all of the .java files were empty. So, since the .java files were empty, no classes were compiled and therefore the googleplaylicensing.jar was empty.

I copied the source files again from the SDK directories, refreshed my project in Eclipse and then built it again and the jar was properly formed.